# Correct an invalid URL in a HTML Anchor snippet

Tags: c#

As an input that I can't 'fix' I am getting a snippet of HTML like

`"<a href='http://someserver/some url/somepage.htm?param+1=test">Some link</a>"`

which needs to be corrected to

`"<a href='http://someserver/some%20url/somepage.htm?param+1=test">Some link</a>"`

Obviously I can parse this, grab the URL, separate out the Query string, pass it through UrlPathEncode and then rebuild...but is there a better way?

Comment: Where / in what kind of application do you get this url and why are you forced to rewrite it?

Comment: Its coming from SharePoint (Client Object Model COM) and query string encoded but path not. Output is an email which is delivered via SendGrid which escapes space in path with + which doesn't work in... SharePoint. Thats all an aside though - TLDR is I can't change the input and output has to be 'correct'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           String abc = "<a href='http://someserver/some url/somepage.htm?param+1=test'>Some link</a>";
           string pattern = @"=['""]([\s\S])+['""]";
           Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
           Match match = rgx.Match(abc);
           if (match.Success)
           {

               abc=abc.Replace(match.Value,match.Value.Replace(" ","%"));
           }
           Console.WriteLine(abc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But jQuery is the answer to all code questions is it not ;) Was after c# code to do server side.

Comment: Nice try but it fails on things like <a target="_blank" href="xxx"> or (malformed) <a href= "xxx"> - just two from top of my head. Thats why I personally hate RegEx's, very hard to be confident they are right.

Comment: if you need it only for href you can change RegEx to this @"href=['""]([\s\S])+['""]" and it will do what you need